# Difference between friend function and getters

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently new to OOP concepts of C++ language like friend of the function and friend of the class .

May be this is not he best comparision between freinds and getters but for the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassB; // forward declaration

class ClassA
{
    int numA;
    friend int add(ClassA, ClassB); // friend function declaration

public:
    ClassA() : numA{12} {} // constructor to initialize numA to 12
};

class ClassB
{
    int numB;
    friend int add(ClassA, ClassB); // friend function declaration

public:
    ClassB() : numB(1) {}
};

// access members of both classes
int add(ClassA objectA, ClassB objectB)
{
    return objectA.numA + objectB.numB;
}

int main()
{
    ClassA objectA;
    ClassB objectB;
    cout << "Sum: " << add(objectA, objectB);

    return 0;
}
```

what if i simply use getter to get the values and add them. The main moto of friend function is to access the  private and public data members (i guess) , and getters are already doing this .

I'm quite confused here.

Comment: If the classes provide suitable (accessible) setters and getters, functions can use them even without being a `friend`.   I normally provide setters and getters for trivial operations (e.g. setting and retrieving value of a private/protected member, with error checking) and implement less trivial operations with non-members that are not friends (but that use the setters and getters).   I only use friend functions if there is a specific (design) reason to not provide suitable setters and getters that they can use.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent talk about this subject here: [CppCon 2017: Klaus Iglberger “Free Your Functions!”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=WLDT1lDOsb4)

My take-away is that if a member function needs no access to the internals of a class, then it should not be a member function. In your case, how will `Class A` be usable? It is not right now, but I imagine you will have something like `explicit operator int() const` or `int get_val() const`. You can simply use this in a free function:

```
A operator+(A lhs, B rhs) {
   return A{lhs.get() + rhs.get()};
}

B operator+(B lhs, A rhs) {
   return B{lhs.get() + rhs.get()};
}

int main() {
   ...
   cout << "sum: " << (objectA + objectB).get() << "\n";
   ...
```

Or something similar.